# Can I call iOS code that contains blocks in a unity wrapper?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, wrapper

I have a method in Objective-C that goes into a NSOperationQueue and returns asynchronously with a block.

eg

`+ (void)getDataFromServer:(void(^)(NSArray *data, NSError *error))block;`

So when I try to call this, with my Objective-C++ wrapper,

```
void get_data(const char *GameObjectName, const char *DataCallback,const char *ErrorCallback){
    [LibraryClass getDataFromServer:^(NSArray *data, NSError *error) {
        if (data) {
             UnitySendMessage(GameObjectName, DataCallback, [[data componentsJoinedByString:@","] UTF8String]);
        }
        if (error) {
            UnitySendMessage(GameObjectName, ErrorCallback, [[error localizedDescription] UTF8String]);
        }
    }];
}
```

If I breakpoint before the block, the strings (`const char *`) are populated fine, but if I breakpoint in the `if (data) {}` section of the block, the variables are munched, to what looks like random data. Of course, UnityMessageSend() fails because the object can't be found.

Am I going about this the right way? I suspect I've forgotten or unaware of some block/C/C++ caveat.

Comment: What's in `getDataFromServer`? Did you make sure to copy the block?

Comment: A series of nested server calls, all wrapped inside NSOperationQueue. 

No, no copy of the block

Comment: If your reference to your block will go out of scope before the block is executed, you need to copy the block. `getDataFromServer` should use something like `block = [ block copy ] ;`

Comment: This also is because local blocks are stack allocated--sending them a `-copy` message moves them to the heap.

Comment: if we assume the original objective-c code is a compiled library and cant change it, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for such.

Comment: I think @erikprice's solution is promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with Erik price in the [CoreInt Slack Channel](https://coreint.slack.com/), but I thought I'd write it up here:

We solved this by having a reference on the class

`@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^myBlock)(NSError *error);`

Then initialising it at the time of the call

`self.myBlock = ^{...};`
then calling it like this
[MyClass getDataFromServer:self.myBlock];

That way, everything was retained correctly.

Happy Coding~

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you'd post the implementation of `- [MyClass getDataFromServer:]`, but at the very least you want to do as @nielsbot has suggested and copy the block from the stack to the heap, using `-copy`:

```
void get_data(const char *GameObjectName, const char *DataCallback,const char *ErrorCallback){
    [LibraryClass getDataFromServer:[^(NSArray *data, NSError *error) {
        if (data) {
             UnitySendMessage(GameObjectName, DataCallback, [[data componentsJoinedByString:@","] UTF8String]);
        }
        if (error) {
            UnitySendMessage(GameObjectName, ErrorCallback, [[error localizedDescription] UTF8String]);
        }
    } copy]];   // <-- call the block's -copy method here
}
```

Comment: This is another possible solution~